# How to diagonalize a >2d array in numpy?

Tags: numpy

Say one has a vector v = [1, 2, 3] in numpy. One uses np.diag to create a diagonal matrix from this vector, to get the following.

```
[[1, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 3]]
```

What if the elements of v themselves are nxm vectors? How to diagonalize that array expediently and fast? Come on, the point is that instead of the 0's we'd have nxm sized zero matrices.

This is what I want:

```
Q = [Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5]
```

Where `Q_i` are `n x m` matrices, i.e., `Q_i.shape = (n, m)`. Therefore, the shape of `Q` is `(5, n, m)`.
Now I want a diagonal matrix:

```
Q_diag =
[[Q1 0 0 0 0]
[0 Q2 0 0 0]
[0 0 Q3 0 0]
[0 0 0 Q4 0]
[0 0 0 0 Q5]]
```

And the `0`'s are in fact themselves `n x m` matrices, that is, have the shape `(n, m)`. So in all the shape of Q_diag would be Q_diag.shape = (5, 5, n, m).

Comment: What is `nxm sized zero matrices`? Won't those constitute a 3D array?

Comment: Explain what you want.  And delete that repeat post.  @Divakar, evidently your duplicate doesn't do what he wants.

Comment: @hpaulj From what I got, it does once you initialize the 3D zeros array. Or what did I miss?

Comment: Added output initialization part in the answer post. Thought that was trivial enough.

Comment: @Divakar, the OP reposed the question after you closed this, indicating that something wasn't answered.  We await clarification.

Comment: @hpaulj, I don't find the answer deemed as "already answered" as significantly similar to this question. I couldn't understand that post at all.

Comment: Your input format is different. So, just permute axes before and after using the posted approches. Specifically use `Q.transpose(1,2,0)` as the input and on the output `out`, do `out.transpose(2,3,0,1)`.